# Calculating Normals across a sphere with a wave-like vertex shader

Tags: math, vector, graphics, normals

I've been trying to get the correct normals for a sphere I'm messing with using a vertex shader. The algorithm can be boiled down simply to

vert.xyz += max(0, sin(time + 0.004*vert.x))*10*normal.xyz

This causes a wave to roll across the sphere.
In order to make my normals correct, I need to transform them as well. I can take the tangent vector at a given x,y,z, get a perpendicular vector (0, -vert.z, vert.y), and then cross the tangent with the perp vector.

I've been having some issue with the math though, and it's become a personal vendetta at this point. I've solved for the derivative hundreds of times but I keep getting it incorrect. How can I get the tangent? 
Breaking down the above line, I can make a math function

f(x,y,z) = max(0, sin(time + 0.004*x))*10*Norm(x,y,z) + (x,y,z)

where Norm(..) is Normalize((x,y,z) - CenterOfSphere)

[After applying f(x,y,z), unchanged normals](http://prntscr.com/5zkpw4)

[image]

What is the correct f '(x,y,z)?

I've accounted for the weirdness caused by the max in f(...), so that's not the issue.

Edit: The most successful algorithm I have right now is as follows:

Tangent vector.x = 0.004*10*cos(0.004*vert.x + time)*norm.x + 10*sin(0.004*vert.x + time) + 1

Tangent vector.y = 10*sin(0.004*vert.x + time) + 1

Tangent vector.z = 10*sin(0.004*vert.x + time) + 1

2nd Tangent vector.x = 0

2nd Tangent vector.y = -norm.z

2nd Tangent vector.z = norm.y

Normalize both, and perform Cross(Tangent2, Tangent1). Normalize again, and done (it should be Cross(Tangent1, Tangent2), but this seems to have better results... more hints of an issue in my math!).

This yields [this](http://prntscr.com/5zm1v3)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get tangent/normal by derivate of function can sometimes fail if your surface points are nonlinearly distributed and or some math singularity is present or if you make a math mistake (which is the case in 99.99%). Anyway you can always use the geometric approach:

**1. you can get the tangents easy by**

- `U(x,y,z)=f(x+d,y,z)-f(x,y,z);`
- `V(x,y,z)=f(x,y+d,z)-f(x,y,z);`
- where `d` is some small enough step
- and `f(x,y,z)` is you current surface point computation
- **not sure why you use 3 input variables I would use just 2**
- but therefore if the shifted point is the same as unshifted
- use this instead `=f(x,y,z+d)-f(x,y,z);`
- at the end do not forget to normalize `U,V` size to unit vector

**2. next step**

- if bullet 1 leads to correct normals
- then you can simply solve the U,V algebraically
- so rewrite `U(x,y,z)=f(x+d,y,z)-f(x,y,z);` to full equation
- by substituting `f(x,y,z)` with the surface point equation
- and simplify

[notes]

- sometimes well selected `d` can simplify normalization to multipliyng by a constant
- you should add normals visualization for example like this:
- [image: surface normals]
- to actually see what is really happening (for debug purposses)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! I was afraid my post would be ignored :)

However, this isn't really what I'm looking for. I had a solution similar earlier involving stepping through in increments, but it wasn't smooth enough for me. I'm implementing this through UE4 (which is why my my axes are so strange), so while I can't implement proper normal visualization I can color it using the xyz values of the normal as rgb which helps.

I'd prefer to have a proper tangent vector and cross it with another to solve for the normal, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my math

Comment: @jmoak3 in that case you should start with reformulating the vertex function to form: `surface_point=f(u,v,t)` because in current state you have vertex on both sides of equation which is in my opinion not a good idea and the cause of your problems. for parameters of function `f` use what you have to not just `u,v,t` that is just example

Comment: @jmoak3 if stepping method is not smooth enough lower `d` if it is still not helping then your equation for surface is not what you think ...

Comment: I'll try it again, your method should work. I'll go ahead and mark it correct, thank you for being knowledgeable and helpful :)